# Call a function to update some variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a collection `lines` i get from ajax call and i use `ng-repeat` and for each item `line` the property `line.date`  need some modification before to be displed

the problem is that I don't know how to call the function to make the modification ?

I try `data-ng-init` and `ng-init` the function is called but the variables are `not updated` !

Html code

```
 <div ng-controller="lineController" data-ng-init="loadLines()">
    <div  ng-repeat="line in lines">
       ...
       <div   data-ng-init="loadDates(line.date)">
         ...
         {{ leftDays}}
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Js code :

```
var app = angular.module("searchModule", []);

app.controller("lineController", function ($scope, $http)
{
    // LOAD LINES AJAX
    $scope.loadLines = function () {

        $http({method: 'GET', url: '..'}).success(function(data) {

            angular.forEach(data.content, function(item, i) {
                $scope.lines.push(item);
            });

        });

    };

    $scope.loadDates = function (date) {
        // complex updating of date variable    
        ....    
        $scope.leftDays = ...; 
    };

});
```

Comment: add some more code or provide a plunker.

Comment: When do you want this function to be called? On click on a DOM element?  When an input changes? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @sp00m no click or input ... i get data from ajax call and i use ng-repeat

Comment: @sp00m i update my question

Comment: Why is the Ajax call(s) not being made before you display the data?

Comment: Couldn't you just call it before pushing it to the array?

Comment: try ng-init or apply or digest but yeah you should make the function first

Comment: @Erez I try `data-ng-init` and `ng-init` the function is called but the variables are not updated

Comment: @KRONWALLED it's a good solution but i wanna learn how to call a funtion to update model variable

Comment: @epascarello i update my question you will understand more

Comment: I would just make the calls directly in `lineController`, where you are declaring the functions. The page view will refresh itself when the `$scope` is changed in the same way as if it was called using `ng-init` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not manage each `line` in you angular.forEach?
Like this :

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '..'}).success(function(data) {

     angular.forEach(data.content, function(item, i) {
          //Do stuff to item here before pushing to $scope.lines
          //item.date = new Date(item.date) blah blah
          $scope.lines.push(item);
     });
});
```

If, you want `line.date` to be displayed in a different way in you html, and dont want to modify the actual data, why not use a $filter for that?
Like this :

```
<span ng-repeat="line in lines">{{line.date|yourCustomFilter}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to do this in this way. You can do this as follows;

```
$scope.loadLines = function () {
  $http({method: 'GET', url: '..'}).success(function(data) {
    angular.forEach(data.content, function(item, i) {
      $scope.lines.push(item);
    });

    $scope.lines.map(function(line) {
      // here is to modify your lines, with a custom
      line.date = $scope.loadDates(line.date);

      return line;
    })
  });
};
```

By the way, I think you can modify your ajax loading function with this;

```
$scope.loadLines = function () {
  $http({method: 'GET', url: '..'}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.lines = data.content.map(function(line) {
      // here is to modify your lines, with a custom
      line.date = $scope.loadDates(line.date);

      return line;
    })
  });
};
```

And if you don't need to use `loadDates` function in view, you don't need to set this function to `$scope`. You can set this function with just `var`. Then you can use that function like; `loadDates(...)` instead of `$scope.loadDates(...)`.

If you don't have to update that $scope.lines variable, you don't need to use .map for this. You can update that function as follows;

```
$scope.loadLines = function () {
  $http({method: 'GET', url: '..'}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.lines = data.content;

    angular.forEach($scope.lines, function(line) {
      // here is to modify your lines, with a custom
      $scope.loadDates(line.date);
    })
  });
};
```